# How to change the image of external background when connected to projector?

Tags: desktop

*OS X El capitan 
version 10.11.6
Macbook pro 13-inch*

Whenever I connect to projector, the projected screen has a old picture of me and it is quite embarrassing when I am presenting in front of professional crowd. I already removed that picture from the Desktop pictures folder but every time I connect projector, it still shows the same.
This is not happening when I connect to external display (monitor) though.How can i change this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you plug into a projector and then use the **Desktop & Screen Saver** Control Panel to change the background of the desktop being projected to something else. The new background should then stay the same anytime you plug a monitor/projector in.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, the desktop picture is stored separately for each desktop you use & can only be edited from System Prefs > Desktop & Screensaver whilst that desktop is in use.

The file that stores them all is at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist`
If you edit that you could at least find where that picture is on your machine & either edit to another picture, or move the original so it can't be found.

It's not something I've ever tried editing & my own .plist isn't much help as I have the same picture across 2 monitors & 6 spaces... so there's a lot of repetition - so you might want to make a backup of it before messing.

Comment: I checked the preferences folder but could not find `com.apple.desktop.plist` file. I might just try to borrow a projector so I can edit this. thanks for the help :)

Comment: Sure you checked the right folder? There definitely should be one there. ~/Lib... not /Lib... copy/paste my path into 'Go to Folder..' in Finder. Oops, sorry, just noticed a typo in my original path, missed a / Fixed.

Comment: Hey, yeah I checked the path you gave. found tons of preference files with `com.apple.something` but there was no `com.apple.desktop.plist`

Comment: That's very odd... I know Spotlight won't find it but [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) (freeware) will, if set to search for invisibles. Might be worth a shot...